# rack.session.options - when to use which?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, session-cookies, rack

Is there a difference between :skip and :defer then apart from :defer tends to be used in older versions? Is there any use case for the various options and when they should be use out there?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I hope a look  [at these comments in the Rack source code](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/deec485/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb#L171-L173) might help you.

```
# :skip will not a set a cookie in the response nor update the session state

# :defer will not set a cookie in the response but still update the session
#   state if it is used with a backend
```